Use json_normalize with extraneous dictionary layer with single key?
I have automated identification system (AIS) data as nested dictionaries in a pandas dataframe.  Here is an example:
dfAIS
Out[18]:
                                                  Message  ...                                           MetaData
0       {'ShipStaticData': {'AisVersion': 1, 'CallSign...  ...  {'MMSI': 255814000, 'MMSI_String': 255814000, ...
1       {'MultiSlotBinaryMessage': {'ApplicationID': {...  ...  {'MMSI': 2276003, 'MMSI_String': 2276003, 'Shi...
2       {'StandardClassBPositionReport': {'AssignedMod...  ...  {'MMSI': 503760500, 'MMSI_String': 503760500, ...
3       {'PositionReport': {'Cog': 25.2, 'Communicatio...  ...  {'MMSI': 211648000, 'MMSI_String': 211648000, ...
4       {'StaticDataReport': {'MessageID': 24, 'PartNu...  ...  {'MMSI': 338467989, 'MMSI_String': 338467989, ...
                                                  ...  ...                                                ...
139625  {'PositionReport': {'Cog': 360, 'Communication...  ...  {'MMSI': 244730300, 'MMSI_String': 244730300, ...
139626  {'PositionReport': {'Cog': 231.5, 'Communicati...  ...  {'MMSI': 219025528, 'MMSI_String': 219025528, ...
139627  {'PositionReport': {'Cog': 360, 'Communication...  ...  {'MMSI': 273252100, 'MMSI_String': 273252100, ...
139628                             {'UnknownMessage': {}}  ...  {'MMSI': 244730043, 'MMSI_String': 244730043, ...
139629  {'ShipStaticData': {'AisVersion': 1, 'CallSign...  ...  {'MMSI': 211666470, 'MMSI_String': 211666470, ...

[139630 rows x 3 columns]

The core data resides in column "Message".  Each element therein is a dictionary with only 1 key and 1 value.  As shown above, the one key might be "ShipStaticData", "MultiSlotBinaryMessage", etc., which we can think of as message types.  Let's call this dictionary the level-1 dictionary.
The level-1 dictionary is an extraneous layer of mapping because the desired data resides in the corresponding value, which itself is an entire dictionary.  Let's call the latter the level-2 dictionary.  As shown above, the fields in the level-2 dictionary can be "AisVersion", "ApplicationID", "Cog", etc.  The valid fields are specified here.
I don't need the key for the level-1 dictionary because the level-2 dictionary contains a MesssageID field that much less ambiguously maps to the message type.  Furthermore, dataframe dfAIS also has a MessageType column not shown above that contains the same label as the sole key in the level-1 dictionary.
I've been educating myself on dataframe manipulations using apply to extract the MessageID from the level-2 dictionary.  I also found that json_normalize is a great option.  Unfortunately, in nested dictionaries, it requires that the hierarchical path to common fields have the same path components.  I cannot use it for the above scenario because Message.ShipStaticData.MessageID is a different path from Message.MultiSlotBinaryMessage.MessageID.  In both of these paths, the 2nd of the 3 path components is the extraneous mapping layer that I wish didn't exist.
How can I un-nest the nested dictionary so that I can access the MessageID field?
I tried using pandas.DataFrame.apply to apply the dictionary method items() to the elements of dfAIS column Message.  It yields a series of nested tuples and
the extraneous message type key is still present:
df = dfAIS.Message.apply(dict.items)

0         ((ShipStaticData, {'AisVersion': 1, 'CallSign'...
1         ((MultiSlotBinaryMessage, {'ApplicationID': {'...
2         ((StandardClassBPositionReport, {'AssignedMode...
3         ((PositionReport, {'Cog': 25.2, 'Communication...
4         ((StaticDataReport, {'MessageID': 24, 'PartNum...
                       
139625    ((PositionReport, {'Cog': 360, 'CommunicationS...
139626    ((PositionReport, {'Cog': 231.5, 'Communicatio...
139627    ((PositionReport, {'Cog': 360, 'CommunicationS...
139628                               ((UnknownMessage, {}))
139629    ((ShipStaticData, {'AisVersion': 1, 'CallSign'...
Name: Message, Length: 139630, dtype: object

P.S. I was also wrestling with how to refer to the labels "ShipStaticData", "MultiSlotBinaryMessage", etc.  They are the keys of the level-1 dictionary.  It would have been convenient to talk about the "value" taken on by the level-1 key, but "value" already refers to the thing that is mapped to by the key.  We can very carefully say that the latter is the value associated with the key, or for the key, but it is still asking for confusion.  Is there a clearer (and succinct) way to refer to "ShipStaticData", "MultiSlotBinaryMessage", etc.?
P.P.S. While the question starts from a dataframe, here is a 3-line sample of the source jsonl file to facilitate answers that might start from data file ingestion:
{"Message": {"ShipStaticData": {"AisVersion": 0, "CallSign": "GDNB   ", "Destination": "AVONMOUTH DREDGING  ", "Dimension": {"A": 30, "B": 5, "C": 7, "D": 3}, "Dte": false, "Eta": {"Day": 0, "Hour": 24, "Minute": 60, "Month": 0}, "FixType": 1, "ImoNumber": 702864, "MaximumStaticDraught": 14, "MessageID": 5, "Name": "MALAGO              ", "RepeatIndicator": 0, "Spare": false, "Type": 33, "UserID": 235065329, "Valid": true}}, "MessageType": "ShipStaticData", "MetaData": {"MMSI": 235065329, "MMSI_String": 235065329, "ShipName": "MALAGO              ", "latitude": 51.50296166666667, "longitude": -2.707621666666667, "time_utc": "2024-04-15 23:00:24.874950587 +0000 UTC"}}
{"Message": {"PositionReport": {"Cog": 226.1, "CommunicationState": 59916, "Latitude": 33.74614666666667, "Longitude": -118.22303833333334, "MessageID": 1, "NavigationalStatus": 0, "PositionAccuracy": false, "Raim": false, "RateOfTurn": 0, "RepeatIndicator": 0, "Sog": 1.1, "Spare": 0, "SpecialManoeuvreIndicator": 0, "Timestamp": 24, "TrueHeading": 11, "UserID": 367693690, "Valid": true}}, "MessageType": "PositionReport", "MetaData": {"MMSI": 367693690, "MMSI_String": 367693690, "ShipName": "KELLY C             ", "latitude": 33.74614666666667, "longitude": -118.22303833333334, "time_utc": "2024-04-15 23:00:24.875182234 +0000 UTC"}}
{"Message": {"Interrogation": {"MessageID": 15, "RepeatIndicator": 3, "Spare": 0, "Station1Msg1": {"MessageID": 316004037, "SlotOffset": 0, "StationID": 316004037, "Valid": true}, "Station1Msg2": {"MessageID": 0, "SlotOffset": 0, "Spare": 0, "Valid": false}, "Station2": {"MessageID": 0, "SlotOffset": 0, "Spare1": 0, "Spare2": 0, "StationID": 0, "Valid": false}, "UserID": 3669987, "Valid": true}}, "MessageType": "Interrogation", "MetaData": {"MMSI": 3669987, "MMSI_String": 3669987, "ShipName": "", "latitude": 47.548895, "longitude": -122.78526333333333, "time_utc": "2024-04-15 23:00:24.875383071 +0000 UTC"}}


People often forget that JSON can be transformed into a dictionary, which is an ordinary data construct in Python and that they can manipulate it before initializing the dataframe. Not everything needs to be handled by pandas.
A little loop before sending it to pandas can make your life a lot easier.
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("data.jsonl") as fp:
    # Loop through each line in the file, parse the JSON, and extract the
    # "Message" field
    messages = [json.loads(line)["Message"] for line in fp]

df = pd.json_normalize(messages)


I'm still getting my Python feet under me and have read the many "unorthodox" looping code patterns (compared to other languages). I'm in the process of figuring out what the code does. The json.load(fp) seems to assume 1 record in the file. I get JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end), which indicates that the reader can't handle multi-record files.

Are you sure your data file is JSON and not JSON Lines? jsonl means 1 line is a complete JSON object, but overall file is invalid JSON. Anyway, include your input for better help.

Thanks for that.  I was unaware that a multi-line file with JSON records actually had a formal name jsonl.  The posted question doesn't start with the source data file.  It starts with a dataframe.  My thinking was sent back to the source data file after reading your answer.  I'll post 3 records from the data file (excluding records that contain binary fields).

Pretty much the same thing. See my updated answer. List comprehension is a god-send feature in Python once you know how to use it. Make you look for it with every other language you work with.

I agree that list comprehension is a god-send for creating containers on the fly.  Your code runs, but creates a lot of dataframe columns because the ShipStaticData dictionary also goes by the name PositionReport, Interrogation, and others.  The main challenge here is to throw away this redundant layer of dictionary, since many of the fields therein are the same.

In the posted question, the dataframe dfAIS contains
a Message field and a MetaData field, as well as a
MessageType field that I described as redundant.
Each of the Message and MessageType fields contains a (possibly nested) dictionary.
I want the fields of the inner most dictionaries to be the columns of
the dataframe.  Here is an example record of the JSON code for one message:
{"Message": {"ShipStaticData": {"AisVersion": 1,
                                "CallSign": "CQUR   ",
                                "Destination": "DELBC               ",
                                <...snip...>
                               }
            },
 "MessageType": "ShipStaticData",
 "MetaData": {"MMSI": 255814000,
              "MMSI_String": 255814000,
              "ShipName": "CORONA SEA          ",
              "latitude": 53.89848666666667,
              "longitude": 10.781958333333334,
              "time_utc": "2024-04-15 23:00:24.770932839 +0000 UTC"
             }
}

The ShipStaticData and MetaData fields above contain the two
inner-most dictionaries whose fields I want to become the new columns
of the dataframe.  The challenging dictionary is ShipStaticData
because (i) it is nested within a 1-item Message dictionary, i.e.,
more deeply than the MetaData dictionary and (ii) it goes by names
other than ShipStaticData.  I just want the fields and values of the
dictionary -- I don't care whether it is called ShipStaticData, nor
that it sometimes goes by different names.  Nor do I care about the
name MetaData -- I just want the dictionaries fields and values.
As described by Code Different, my source data file is a JSONL file containing multiple lines/records, one message per record.  Furthermore, it is gzipped.  The first half of the code below reads all the records into a list of dictionaries while the 2nd half takes the
fields of the ShipStaticData and MetaData dictionaries and turns
the fields into dataframe columns:
import os
import gzip
import json
import pandas as pd

# Working directory (chokes on Windows backslashes)
os.chdir("C:/cygwin64/home/User.Name/prj/Project.Name/aisstream-logger")

# 1st half
#----------
AISmsgs = []
fpINgz="data/20240415/ais_messages_185928.662241.json.gz"
    # Relative path to data file
with gzip.open(fpINgz,'rt',encoding='UTF-8') as zipfile:
   for JsonObj in zipfile:
      AISmsg1 = json.loads(JsonObj)
      AISmsgs.append(AISmsg1)

# 2nd half
#---------
dfMsg = pd.DataFrame([
   next(iter( rec1['Message'].values() )) | rec1['MetaData']
   for rec1 in AISmsgs # For each record
])

The | operator concatenates the ShipStaticData and MetaData
dictionaries.  Expressions rec1['Message'] and rec1['MetaData']
simply accesses the two dictionaries for each record.  The Message
dictionary requires more processing because it is the inner ShipStaticData
dictionary that I want:

rec1['Message'] returns a dictionary in which ShipStaticData is
the sole key
rec1['Message'].values() returns the "value" for the
ShipStaticData key, which itself is one of the two innermost
dictionaries whose keys I want to turn into dataframe columns
dictionary
More accurately, a dictionary's values() function returns an iterable.  Since ShipStaticData is the sole key, the iterable can only iterate over one value, which is the innermost dictionary corresponding to the ShipStaticData key.
However, rec1['Message'].values() is of <class 'dict_values'>,
"which does not support indexing [so I can't actually access the
value].  But it's iterable, it can be converted to list, which
supports indexing" (see
here)

The following has the effect of : (i) converting rec1['Message'].values()
to a single-item list containing the value corresponding to the key
ShipStaticData, i.e., the dictionary whose fields I want to become
dataframe columns; and (ii) accessing the single item in the list:
list( AISmsgs[0]['Message'].values() )[0] # Simplest
next(iter( AISmsgs[0]['Message'].values() )) # Most efficient

Here is a sanity check of the correctness of converting data from the
list of nested dictionaries AISmsgs to dataframe dfMsg based on
the first record:
AISmsgs[0]

   {'Message': {'ShipStaticData': {'AisVersion': 1,
      'CallSign': 'CQUR   ',
      'Destination': 'DELBC               ',
      'Dimension': {'A': 26, 'B': 161, 'C': 13, 'D': 13},
      'Dte': False,
      'Eta': {'Day': 15, 'Hour': 16, 'Minute': 0, 'Month': 4},
      'FixType': 1,
      'ImoNumber': 9357597,
      'MaximumStaticDraught': 6.3,
      'MessageID': 5,
      'Name': 'CORONA SEA          ',
      'RepeatIndicator': 0,
      'Spare': False,
      'Type': 71,
      'UserID': 255814000,
      'Valid': True}},
    'MessageType': 'ShipStaticData',
    'MetaData': {'MMSI': 255814000,
     'MMSI_String': 255814000,
     'ShipName': 'CORONA SEA          ',
     'latitude': 53.89848666666667,
     'longitude': 10.781958333333334,
     'time_utc': '2024-04-15 23:00:24.770932839 +0000 UTC'}}

dfMsg.iloc[0]

   AisVersion                                          1.0
   CallSign                                        CQUR
   Destination                        DELBC
   Dimension         {'A': 26, 'B': 161, 'C': 13, 'D': 13}
   Dte                                               False
   Eta    {'Day': 15, 'Hour': 16, 'Minute': 0, 'Month': 4}
   FixType                                             1.0
   ImoNumber                                     9357597.0
   MaximumStaticDraught                                6.3
   MessageID                                           5.0
   Name                               CORONA SEA
   RepeatIndicator                                     0.0
   Spare                                             False
   Type                                               71.0
   UserID                                      255814000.0
   Valid                                              True
   MMSI                                          255814000
   MMSI_String                                   255814000
   ShipName                           CORONA SEA
   latitude                                      53.898487
   longitude                                     10.781958
   time_utc        2024-04-15 23:00:24.770932839 +0000 UTC

   ApplicationID                                       NaN
   ApplicationIDValid                                  NaN
   CommunicationState                                  NaN
    <...snip...>
   AltFromBaro                                         NaN
   Altitude                                            NaN
   Text                                                NaN
   Name: 0, dtype: object

At the very bottom is a long series of mysterious fields containing
NaN.  The first record in the source data file contains none of
these fields.  I tracked this down to the fact that not all of the
records follow the data model shown at the top of this answer.  To
avoid this inconsistency, I need to find a way to add a column to
the original data set containing MessageID, which I will filter on.
That has strong prospects of leaving records that have the same data
model.
